Saving web scrape API call output as a JSON file
I am trying to save the output from my API call to a JSON file so that i can parse it properly. I am getting all sorts of errors.
Below is my code:
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

import serpapi
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv('SERPAPI_KEY')
client = serpapi.Client(api_key=api_key)

results  = client.search({'engine': 'google_maps_reviews','type': 'search','place_id': 'ChIJidRKt32YVogRN6fEPG9Kuho'})

data = json.loads(results.json)


What are the errors? also the client.search() should return a json object by default,
and I don't think it has a .json attribute, you might not even need to use json.loads()

I think you just need to coerce the results to string before parsing?
Try this:
import os
import json

import serpapi
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv('SERPAPI_KEY')
client = serpapi.Client(api_key=api_key)

results  = client.search({
    'engine': 'google_maps_reviews',
    'type': 'search',
    'place_id': 'ChIJidRKt32YVogRN6fEPG9Kuho'
})

# Convert results to string before parsing JSON.
#
data = json.loads(str(results))

with open("results.json", "wt") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

I dumped the data to a JSON file and loaded into a JSON viewer. This is what the structure looks like:

